# How to remove limiter from product listing page in Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1

I want to remove just limiter from bottom toolbar in product listing page.
[image]
I've tried following code but not working, In local `catalog_category_view.xml`

```
  <referenceBlock name="product_list_toolbar_limiter" remove="true" />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create this file in your theme:

```
Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list/toolbar.phtml
```

Copy from origianl file in:

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list/toolbar.phtml
```

Comment out this line (or remove it)

```
include ($block->getTemplateFile('Magento_Catalog::product/list/toolbar/limiter.phtml'))
```

Comment: Is this the only way?? Can't we do it via xml so we don't have to create these files??

Comment: @KaushalSuthar From a code it turns out that it is the only way, since there are no special conditions for this block.

Comment: @KaushalSuthar I don't think this is correct. To me it looks like this code will remove both top and bottom limiters. The OP wants to remove the bottom one only.

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism : Hi, Well as of my requirement right-now I want the toolbar only in bottom I've commented $block->getToolbarHtml() in list.phtml in starting but I would like to know if you have some way to do so...And that limiter is coming only in bottom toolbar....

Answer (score 0):

Add this CSS to your `_theme.less` or `_extend.less`

```
.products.wrapper ~ .toolbar .limiter {
    display: none;
}
```